# Why i can't send local storage name to backend

Tags: javascript, ionic2, angular2-services

I am working with ionic 2 application i need to send my local storage username to back end . i try to something like this which i can not send. please try to figure out where i did wrong.

```
public username:string;

  constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.get('name').then((val) => {
      this.username = val;
    })
  }
chart(){
     let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
      return this.http.post('http://node.futures.com:9000/chart/',JSON.stringify({username:this.username}),options).map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Comment: `...which I can not send` - what error are you receiving when making the request?

Comment: I wrote backend sql query which is based on username i can not get any response. i got server error which can not read property of undefined. where i sent manually JSON.stringify({username:'myname'}) which works fine and i got data also where as getting from storage is problem. it looks something async issue.